# Adding Opacity on a graduated Layer PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, transparency-opacity, upgrade

My code is:

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsProject,
    QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer,
    QgsSymbol,
    QgsRendererRangeLabelFormat
)
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from pathlib import Path
import requests

# caminho e nome do arquivo geopackage
file_path = r"C:/Users/felip/Desktop/automation_consumption/src/services/qgis/setores_porto_alegre.gpkg"
layer_name = "setores_porto_alegre"

# criar a camada
layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"{file_path}|layername={layer_name}", layer_name, "ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
    print(f"Não foi possível carregar a camada {layer_name} do arquivo {file_path}")
else:
    # adicionar a camada ao projeto
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

    
    ## Set layer name and desired paremeters
    layer_name = layer_name
    ramp_name = 'Spectral'
    value_field = 'gasto_medio_setor'
    num_classes = 7
    classification_method = QgsClassificationJenks() 

    layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    # change format settings as necessary
    format = QgsRendererRangeLabelFormat()
    format.setFormat("%1 - %2")
    format.setPrecision(2)
    format.setTrimTrailingZeroes(True)

    default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
    color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp(ramp_name)
    color_ramp.invert()

    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer()
    renderer.setClassAttribute(value_field)
    renderer.setClassificationMethod(classification_method)
    renderer.setLabelFormat(format)
    renderer.updateClasses(layer, num_classes)
    renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)

  
    layer.setRenderer(renderer)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    # Add the vector layer to the project
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    service_url = "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
    service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url="+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
    tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Satellite", "wms")

    service_url = "mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}" 
    service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url=https://"+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
    tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Road", "wms")
```

How can I add some opacity?

Comment: E.g. `layer.setOpacity(0.5)` [link to doc](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a68bdfb724b0f14644aeaf79e1e0f525f)